# Display invalid/unavailable in output field?

Tags: fields

We have to display a value in output fields that comes either from invalid data, unavailable data or an invalid parameter (in a calculation).
The value can be invalid by a performed calculation, can be shown on a message, protocol and PDF report, and should be persisted.

Options I've come up with for displaying the invalid value:

- Text: (like [invalid data], [unavailable data], [invalid parameter] with tool tip incl. description of error
- Sign: (like "?", "-" with tool tip incl. description of error
- Code: (like "#Value!", "#N/A", "#Parameter!" (like Excel do) with or without tool tip incl. description of error?

What is the best way to show these different output values to the user?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Todd that signs and secret codes are not intuitive and confusing for many users. It is something they can learn, but using plain english is always a better option. I'd take it a step further and say you should use explicit phrasing. For instance "Invalid" doesn't give the user a way to understand what has caused the error. You should strive to give the user the right information so they can fix the invalid state and become successful in their task.

Answer (score 1):

Signs and secret codes can be confusing for users and without extra indicators their meanings may not be very obvious. Spelling it out in plain English, using the the words "Invalid" and "Unavailable" seem to make more sense for me as an end user.